# Does iverilog support "int unsigned" of SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog, iverilog

I tried to simulate [`cvfpu`](https://github.com/openhwgroup/cvfpu)(a floating-point unit written in SystemVerilog) with **iverilog**, but the compiler gave up every time when there was `parameter int unsigned` in source code even if I added `-g2005-sv`.  Does it mean that `int unsigned` is not supported by **iverilog**? And I'll also be appreciated that you can tell me how to simulate SystemVerilog codes, like `cvfpu`, with iverilog (not vcs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iverilog` does not support all SystemVerilog features.

I tried a trivial example on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/UvWN) using the latest version of `iverilog` which is available there, and it also generates a syntax error.  It uses the `-g2012` option to enable SystemVerilog features.  The example compiles without errors with other simulators on that site.

If you want to continue to use `iverilog`, you can try to contact the developers to see if a newer version is available.

Otherwise, you need to use a different simulator to run simulations with this syntax.

Answer (score -1):

It is worth mentioning that EDA Playground currently only has very old versions of `iverilog` avaliable. The latest released version of `iverilog` is V12 and their latest version is a preliminary (development) version of V10 from over 8 years ago. V12 was released half a year ago so a lot has changed since the V10 version they are providing.